# MYSQL how to delete duplicates based on match after a hyphen

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete, partial-matches

I have a list of names in my table as follows:

```
paul-jones
Ron-Thomas
John-Doe
Michael-Adams
Jim-Jones
Adam-Jones
Bob-Thomas
Bill-Thomas
```

I would like to delete all rows where last name after hypen is duplicate but would like to keep oldest row for each last name.
For example in the above data set I would like to delete

```
    Jim-Jones
    Adam-Jones
    Bob-Thomas
    Bill-Thomas
```

and keep

```
paul-jones
Ron-Thomas
John-Doe
Michael-Adams
```

and so on.

I found the below query to extract all charecter after hyphen like this
`select SUBSTRING_INDEX(full_name,'-',-1) from names;` but couldn't figure out how to update last_name column in my table with these values, so that I can delete based on unique values in my last_name column using this query maybe

```
("ALTER IGNORE TABLE names ADD UNIQUE (`last_name`)") ;
```

I hope this clearly explains my question.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: can you show a tbale with data and the result you want

Comment: what determines which one you keep?  why delete adam-jones and keep paul-jones, not the other way around?  if there is some order, what is it based on?

Comment: @ysth - I would like to keep the oldest one and delete the rest.

Comment: great, but you haven't shown us anything that tells what is oldest.  could you show the output of `show create table yourtablename` and sample rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` in your UPDATE query to update `last_name`.

```
UPDATE product
SET last_name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(supplier_reference,'-',-1)
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(supplier_reference,'-',-1) != ''
AND last_name = '';
```

`WHERE` clause will ensure that the query updates last name only if there is a value after hyphen.

And then, if you want to delete duplicate rows but retain oldest one based on `last_name`,

```
DELETE FROM product
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT MIN(id)
    FROM product
    GROUP BY last_name
)
```

If you have auto-incremented value `id` then `MIN(id)` will ensure oldest record is retained. To test, instead of `DELETE` try `SELECT * FROM product` and verify if these are the records you want deleted.

Please note, this query will also delete duplicate rows where `last_name` is empty. If you don't want that, then add a clause `WHERE last_name != ''` in the subquery.

Comment: Hi @Samir, Is there a way to run the update query to only update last_name column if it doesnt have any value ? For example data is constantly added to this table, and i would be running this query multiple times, so why update the previously updated values again with the same value, just update the values if there is none in last_name column.

Comment: @Abey, Yes we can do so. I have added `AND last_name = ''` clause in the update query.

Comment: Thank you Samir :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a separate last_name column (though having first and last name columns *instead* of your current column would be a great idea), you can just delete as is:

```
create table names (id int not null primary key auto_increment, name varchar(63), order_column int not null);
insert into names (name,order_column) values ('Paul-Jones',1),('Ron-Thomas',2),('John-Doe',3),('Michael-Adams',4),('Jim-Jones',5),('Adam-Jones',6),('Bob-Thomas',7),('Bill-Thomas',8);
delete n2 from names n1
join names n2 on
    instr(n1.name,'-') and
    instr(n2.name,'-') and
    substring_index(n1.name,'-',-1)=substring_index(n2.name,'-',-1) and
    n2.id<>n1.id and
    n2.order_column>n1.order_column;
```

It sounds like you have some date or something to identify the oldest record; use whatever that is where I have order_column.

Comment: This query has been running for past 12 hours in the background, i ran it from phpmyadmin, the browser session expired, but show processlist; command shows that its still running and i dont see any duplicates removed just yet, as the number of rows is still the same. see image here : https://ibb.co/YdBYGBM

Comment: Yes I have a date column and I used it in place of order_column like you mentioned

Comment: wow; how many rows are there in the table?  sounds like you do need a last name column (with an index)

Comment: Yeah , its about 4 mil records now and growing. :) I tried Samir's solution below and it looks promising , using SUBSTRING_INDEX i was able to update last_name columns and run ("ALTER IGNORE TABLE names ADD UNIQUE (`last_name`)") ; to delete duplicates in less than 15 minutes on the table.

Comment: Thank you @ysth for the help :)